# Python Dask Apply Function and STore Result in Same Column

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

Hello i am bit new on Dask and i am trying to do the following things

i have a CSV file I am reading file everything works fine

```py
import pandas 
import os
import json

import math
import numpy as np

import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as df
import dask.multiprocessing
client = Client(n_workers=3, threads_per_worker=4, processes=False, memory_limit='2GB')

df = df.read_csv("netflix_titles.csv")
```

now i have function

```py
def toupper(x):
    return x.upper()
```

i would like to apply this to a  column now the issue is want to save the result in same column seems like i cannot do that

```
df["title"].map(toupper).compute()
```

The following line works but i want

```
df["title"] = df["title"].map(toupper).compute()
```

ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.

Image
[image]

Comment: Conventionally, ``import dask.dataframe as dd`` not ``as df``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this after `read_csv`.

```
df.title = df.title.map(toupper)
df.to_csv("netflix_titles.csv", index=False, single_file=True)
```

`to_csv` has a optional argument with default value`compute=True` so you don't need to explicit do `compute()`.

Comment: No still giving error
or: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.

df.title = df["title"].map(toupper).compute()

Comment: @SoumilNitinShah Could you show me you csv file or maybe 10 lines of it? and which python and dask version are u using?

Comment: Thanks for getting back i am not sure if I can paste the image in the comment of how CSV looks like 

but here is my version of dask 

Version: 2020.12.0

Comment: i have added the image to the description please check above image

Comment: @SoumilNitinShah Hey, I still cannot reproduce your error. However, I notice you are using jupyter. Could you double check you execute cells in the order you expect? And didn't rerun cells accidentally.

Comment: Hello sir thanks for getting back first of all 
i still have error here is my notebook with csv file on github 
https://github.com/soumilshah1995/Stackoverflow-issue-

Comment: I didn't call ``compute()`` in any part of my code.

Comment: First of all i would like to say thanks for taking out time and looking into issue very few people do that thanks my error is resolved